# nn*m matrix with neuralnet in R

Tags: r, matrix, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

If I have a n*m A-matrix (Ai,j) `1<i<n, 1<j<m`, and I want to build a neural net (with neuralnetpackage in R) transforming columns `(Ai,k)` in `(Ai,k+1)`.

I tried to make it with formula `=A[,k]~A[,k+1]` and `data=A`, but there's this message

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula.reverse, data) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'EU[,j + 1]'
```

My goal is to build a neuralnet with m>>n to analyse scaling laws.

Can someone help me in this field?

Comment: Could you post your code and format it as such?

Comment: net<- neuralnet(A[,k]~A[k+1], A, hidden=10)